# CSS rules are simply not applied in Internet Explorer. Where should I look for more info?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I don't have a lot of information here.  My site has been working in IE8, but now no styles are applied. The developer tools show all of the CSS files being *loaded,* but no elements show any evidence of those styles being *applied.*  Chrome & Firefox still apply all styles with no problem.

I know you can't help me without more information, but maybe you have an idea of where I could look for an error?  All of my javascript is running fine.  Is it possible that an invalid CSS file would just stop all style application, or something like that?

Thanks for any suggestions!

PS: possibly relevant - my base css file imports several others - about 8 in total.

Comment: Whats shown in IE developer tools?

Comment: Just to confirm, if you view the page source in IE, click on the CSS link, the CSS code opens? or does it say file not found?

Comment: Try clearing your IE cache. Try resaving your CSS files under a new name (hopefully temporarily). Also validate your stylesheets again.

Comment: @rahul - no styles are attached to any of the elements.  @dpmguise - yes, the CSS code opens if I follow those steps.  @BoltClock - good ideas, but no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just on a lark, try removing all the imports then putting them back in one by one.
2. Run your CSS through the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input).
3. Attach a new CSS file, test that it works, then slowly migrate across to the new file until it breaks. Try to track down where it breaks.

Comment: So did running the Validator reveal anything useful?

Answer (score 1):

There is a cap on number of css files that can be included in a page on IE. Check if u are including lot(>31) of css files refer http://drupaleasy.com/quicktips/internet-explorer-css-file-limits

Answer (score 0):

Look at the files that do get imported, say, based on `body`, and see if they appear chopped off. That will show a syntax error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand - how do I look at the files that do get imported?  The developer tools show the body tag has no styles applied (even though one of my stylesheets does attempt to apply one).  Nothing looks chopped off.

Comment: Sorry, I was implying looking at them with FireBug (with Firefox). If you can find an element that had the `body` tag inherited from the CSS file, you can then click on the name of the file to open it up and see if it appears truncated. if you don't have a `body` element defined, just create one: `body { color:blue; }

Comment: Everything is working fine in Firefox.  The developer tools of IE do show my entire cascade of styles on the body element... but none of them seem to actually take effect.

Comment: Does it happen on other computers? Different OS? Try Shift+Refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Even if one css file had an error (say an unclosed curly brace) that made the entire file invalid, it shouldn't affect other css files. I'm assuming you don't have html comments around all of your includes....  It's possible you're doing something systematically that invalidates all css. Try adding this code at the top of your document (let's just say below any doctype, just because), and see if that affects anything:

```
<style type="text/css">
* { background: #f00 !important; }
</style>
```

Comment: Good idea - I added that directly below my stylesheet include, and everything turned red.  I also tried adding it directly above my stylesheet link, and everything turned red again.

Comment: Secondly, you might try putting that rule at the top of one of your stylesheets and see what happens.

Comment: Fascinatingly / infuriatingly, putting this rule in one of the stylesheets turns everything red as well.  Hard to tell if IE is just doing some weird semi-caching or what.  So, the stylesheets are loading... but not applying to elements.  Actually, though everything is being _rendered_ in red, the red background doesn't show up anywhere in the DOM displayed in the developer tools.

Comment: Hm, an update: setting the color to yellow in one of the included css files flashes the background yellow when the page loads, but then it reverts to white.  It must be unapplied by something...

Comment: So, if this rule is set as the last rule in the last file to be imported by the master css file, it is reverted after a short flash.  If this rule is set as the first rule AFTER the last file is imported by the master css file, it stays.  So, IE seems to be loading all of the rules in each imported CSS file, and then unloading them after the file is read.

Comment: I've restarted IE a really frustrating number of times.

Comment: I hear your pain. The overwriting thing is weird! Any way you can upload the HTML/css source somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your help - I'll work on getting a smaller subset of code ready for public review.  Probably tomorrow - it's late and I don't want to break my keyboard.  It's already too late for the mouse - and the window I threw it through.

Comment: Sounds good.  Maybe shrinking it down will help isolate your problem, too :)

Answer (score 0):

check if you have mentioned DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd in your file... I faced similar problem once.

Not sure if it'd works but give it a try.